# jquery pdf reader - search plugin

Tags: javascript, pdf, view

I need plugin to read pdf files some like this :

[example](http://gimnazjum.zpopiekoszow.pl/new/index.php?show=pdf)
[Plugin homepage](http://issuu.com/home)

But this plugin is paid. So I am looking for a similar free alternative. He knows someone can such a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

try using this one: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/
pdf reader javascript

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I search "book effect" on my pdf's